# git tag fails with "fatal: bad object type" in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, tags, azure-pipelines, ado

I have a pipeline task to tag a commit which looks like the following:

```
  - job:
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
    - powershell: |
        $longBuildNumber = '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
        $tag = "RC" + $longBuildNumber
        $commitSha = '$(resources.pipeline.build-all.sourceCommit)'
        Write-Host $tag
        Write-Host $commitSha
        $tagComment = "Testing "
        git config --global user.name "BuildService"
        git config --global user.email "buildservice@pipeline.com"
        git tag -a $tag $commitSha -m $tagComment
        git push --tags
```

the commit SHA is being fed in from another pipeline, called 'build-all', that builds the relevant artefacts.

The user can select which build to tag from clicking 'Resources' below
[image]

click on the Pipeline name which will list the completed Runs (and artefacts)

[image]

Selecting an artefact sometimes worked and sometimes didn't work, returning the following message.

```
RC20230717.60
9f9b86b7cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
fatal: bad object type.
Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 2):

This is for anyone facing the same issue, the answer is to put

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

before trying to tag, this will fetch all the missing data and ref information, making the local repository contain the complete history, just like a regular non-shallow clone.